# Cannot install mysql2 gem on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I have 8.0.30 version of mysql and ruby v3.0.4 installed. I'm able to run mysql on my system and create databases but I cannot run this command:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.4' -- '--with-mysql-lib="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib" --withmysql-include="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"'
```

I getting following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for -lmysqlclient... no
-----
mysql client is missing. Check your installation of MySQL or Connector/C, and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Comment: (1) It should generally be `--with-mysql-include` (with an additional hyphen). (2) You should not quote all the arguments together. Remove the single quotes. (3) As an alternative to specifying each directory individually, you may also use `--with-mysql-dir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0"`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the client lib files (not just the server) installed locally?

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/c-api/

I know this isn't a direct solution, but I'd strongly encourage having a look at developing under WSL2. Developing Ruby apps under native Windows often involves a lot more mucking about that just using the Linux subsystem.

Comment: Yes I installed lib files locally

Comment: Hmm... assuming the client lib has been installed in your ..MySQL Server 8.0\lib and ...MySQL Server 8.0\include folders, it *should* work. Shot in the dark here, but maybe try the MariaDB client libraries instead. Sorry, not much help.

Comment: It seems to be falling over somewhere in here. I wonder, does mysqlclient.dll have to be on the path?  Clutching at straws - sorry 
 
 https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/ba4d46551d132492b34205cdb8fa224c92765bef/ext/mysql2/extconf.rb#L83

Comment: yep, dlls need to be in your path under windows.  I did start down this route myself, before using WSL2, but I'm already comfortable with Linux

Comment: I installed MariaDB and then used `gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-lib="path_to:\MariaDB 10.5\"` , gem intalled :)